# Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2010 Public Folder Replication

Tags: exchange-2010, public-folders

We have 2 exchange servers in our org. MX1 and MX2. I'm trying to replicate all MX1 public folders to MX2. I've setup replication for all the toplevel folders to include the MX2 server. However no public folders are being replicated. The event log does not show any errors. I've set the diagnostic level for all public folder diagnostics to Highest using

```
get-eventloglevel "MSExchangeIS\9001 Public\*" | set-eventloglevel -Level Expert
```

However besides a 3092 event ID (type: 0x2) generated on MX1 (the source server), there are no events being generated that would notify me of any issues.

Some technical details. MX1 is Windows 2008 Standard, MX2 is Windows 2008 Enterprise (eval mode right now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally fixed it. Seemed to be an empty Server's containers in the AD which used to hold the now decommissioned Exchange 2003 server. See tip 2 @ http://workinghardinit.wordpress.com/2010/05/25/exchange-2007-2010-public-folders-issues-the-active-directory-user-wasnt-found/ For some reason I guess that was holding up the replication process. Sad it wasn't giving me errors in the event log.

Answer (score 1):

The settings are not recursive.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997966.aspx for a list of scripts that are supplied with Exchange 2010 to help with what you want to do.

You will probably want to run `AddReplicaToPFRecursive.ps1`

Comment: Hi Phil, I had used the MoveAllReplicas.ps1 script. I also double checked all folders uptil 2 levels deep.